# Bug with repeat sine sound

Tags: c#, .net, naudio

What is my code:

```
void SpeakThreadFunction()
    {
        while (SpeakThreadState)
        {
            Speaker.Play();
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            Speaker.Stop()
            Thread.Sleep(Interval);
        }
    }
//Speaker is WaveOut
```

And `Speaker.Init` is `SineWaveProvider32`.

```
public class SineWaveProvider32 : WaveProvider32
{
    int sample;

    public SineWaveProvider32()
    {
        Frequency = 1000;
        Amplitude = 0.25f;       
    }

    public float Frequency { get; set; }
    public float Amplitude { get; set; }

    public override int Read(float[] buffer, int offset, int sampleCount)
    {
        int sampleRate = WaveFormat.SampleRate;
        for (int n = 0; n < sampleCount; n++)
        {
            buffer[n + offset] = (float)(Amplitude * Math.Sin((2 * Math.PI * sample * Frequency) / sampleRate));
            sample++;
            if (sample >= sampleRate) sample = 0;
        }
        return sampleCount;
    }
}
```

After 10-15 iterations on my cycle, sound is stop :(. What i need to do, to my sound repeat all time?

Answer (score 0):

You won't have much success trying to continually start and stop the soundcard like that. The default WaveOut buffer sizes in NAudio are 100ms long. It would be much better to open the soundcard once, and then send it portions of sine wave, followed by zeroes, to create the sound you want.